# Cream Ale vs Stout

Tags: stout, ale

Hey I'm trying to figure out the difference between a beer like Guinness (Stout) vs Six Point Sweet Action ([Cream Ale](http://www.beersmith.com/Recipes2/recipe_140.htm))

Comment: I am assuming you are looking for the difference in the ingredients?  If not please clarify your question.

Comment: @Chooey245 Thanks guys! To clarify I just wanted to know what is the main ingredient that distinguishes a Stout to an Ale. Is it the malt or type of yeast?

Comment: Stout is an ale so if that's the question, there is no difference between them.

Comment: @brewchez that is helpful. Is there any main ingredient that separates a stout from the superset ale?

Comment: @user3795309 The judicious amount of roasted malt character.  But then you get into the blurred lines between stout and porter (also an ale).

Answer (score 1):

Dry Irish Stout (Guinness) is a dark to black ale with chocolate/cacao flavours and aromas.

A Cream Ale is similar to a Budweiser, but brewed with ale yeast instead of lager yeast. Flavour and aroma on a cream ale is low to none.

Some brewers (like Kilkenny) call their beer a cream ale because it has a creamy mouthfeel (from the nitro).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking what the difference is in regards to ingredients, flavor, color, taste, etc.
Stouts and Cream Ales are quite different across the board.
Here's a link to the BJCP (Beer Judge Certification Program) most recently updated style guideline. You can find information on Cream Ales on page 1 and depending on the style of Stout you are looking for, you can find them on other pages (Irish Stouts on page 27, Oatmeal Stouts page 28, etc.)
The BJCP style guidelines is my go-to for anything beer related because it gives you a total break down on the characteristics of each style.

If you are asking in terms of ingredients, here are some recipes I was able to find that will show you the differences in terms of brewing Cream Ales and Stouts.

Here is a link for a [Stout Recipe](https://byo.com/stories/issue/item/3344-winter-yum-yum-stout)

Here is a link for a [Cream Ale Recipe](http://www.beersmith.com/Recipes2/recipe_140.htm)